# How we can use setTimeout function multiple time in a single page without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, function, settimeout, setinterval

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title modal-title-100">New call by  <small id="callertype"></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="acceptcall" onclick="acceptcall()" data-dismiss="modal"> Accept</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="declinecall" onclick="declinecall()" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 // Code to show popup on new call 
  setInterval(function () {
        console.log('Modal.show()');
          $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
          calltimeout();
      //}
  }, 3000);

  function calltimeout(){
  setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("timeout");
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
     }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds
 }

</script>

</html>
```

I am running a PHP page, where I have used a setInterval function which refresh my div section after every 2 seconds. Based on my div content I display a Modal. What I need is to hide Modal after 1 minute of its appearance. For this I have used setTimeout function but it runs only once. 
I just need to run setTimeout function every time to hide Modal.

My set Interval function is:

```
setInterval(function () {
$("#refreshme").load(location.href + " #refreshme");
  // var flagstate = calltimeOut();
  //   if(flagstate==0){
    //console.log('Modal.show()');
    var curval      = $("#curval").val();
    var callby      = $("#callby").val();
    var callstatus  = $("#callstatus").val();
    //console.log(callstatus);
    if(curval==1 && callstatus==0){
      $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
      $('#callertype').html(callby);
    }}, 3000);
```

My setTimeout Functions is:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("timeout");
}, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

Please help me to fix this issue or provide me alternative issue for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your setTimeout is showing 10 seconds delay instead of 1 second and where are you calling this? Please post relevant code so that we can help you better

Comment: I need to call this function just after Modal appearance. For example, if come one make call on cell phone, if receiver pick the call then okay, if not then after 1 minute the call becomes missed call. and this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have try to call my timeout function in setIntrval function but it not works.

Comment: setTimeout should work if you put time out script right after `$('#myModal').modal`. Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: Please Check I have added my code,

Comment: did you find anything on conole?

Comment: Yes, first it show "Modal.show()" which I have displayed in setInterval, and after given time in setTimeout funcion I am getting "timeout" in console.

Now the problem is the functions become a infinity loop, it display modal and then it all timeout function. See my above code in snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why you're running `setInterval` to remove and re-show the modal box.

Comment: Let Me explain what I am trying to do.
I am working on video conferencing, visitor make a call to owner. once visitor call to owner I save it to database for call status. on Owner panel, I get call status and based on its value I show Modal.
To get latest value I have to refresh the div where I am getting the value of call status. Rest Functionality is working very fine. I just need to hide Modal if owner do not take any action on new call. like we do in our phone calls.

Comment: @VikasGhai, so you need to show modal only on first refresh to the owner right?

Comment: @VikasGhai: I still don't quite get it. It doesn't seem to make sense if there is no status update while you still re-pop your modal box.  Also the frequency you're poping the modal box (every 3 seconds) is much higher than it is expected for the modal box to go away (10 seconds or 1 minute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are refreshing page for every 3 seconds but you have set time out of 10 seconds to hide modal instead of 1 second. This is the reason you cannot see modal hiding even after div refreshed.

I have corrected 10 seconds (10000) to 1 second (1000)and seems like your code is working as expected

CORRECTION: OP need to set time out for 1 min and not 1 second. I am showing modal conditionally.

```js
var modalshown = false;
// Code to show popup on new call 
  setInterval(function () {
         if(!modalshown) {
         console.log('Modal.show()');
          $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
          modalshown = true;
          
          calltimeout();
          }
      //}
  }, 3000);

  function calltimeout(){
  setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("timeout");
       $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        modalshown = false;
     }, 100000); // <-- time in milliseconds
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>



<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title modal-title-100">New call by  <small id="callertype"></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="acceptcall" onclick="acceptcall()" data-dismiss="modal"> Accept</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="declinecall" onclick="declinecall()" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: I have to show modal for 1 minute, and after 1 minute is must hide automatically. Refresh Div is just for to show modal. In my refresh Div, I am getting record from my database. and based on the record I am showing Modal.

Comment: you are refreshing the div data for every 2 seconds and after loading div data you are showing the modal and setting time out for 1 minute but this will keep on refreshing the modal and your timeout will never happen because new timeout is getting set every time before old one get expires. Either you have to set refreshing time more than 1 minute or put condition to show modal only if first modal get hidden

Comment: will you please let me know HOW I can do it?

Comment: see my updated post where i have used one local variable to know when modal is shown and when timeout expires

Comment: I think this will work, but I have to add some more functionality in it. I will use your code and will back to you, Thanks @bhushan

Comment: happy to help you :) .. you can upvote and accept this answer if find it useful

Comment: it works, there was just a single error in my previous code,,, I use your way and correct my old code... Thanks once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job.Install **node-cron**.

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('1000 0 0 0 0 0 * ', setTimeout = () => {
   console.log("Every second fuction should be calling.");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this?

```js
(function ($) {

  // just refresh the callertype content
  setInterval(function () {

    $("#refreshme").load(location.href + " #refreshme");
    var curval      = $("#curval").val();
    var callby      = $("#callby").val();
    var callstatus  = $("#callstatus").val();

    // trigger modal box if needed
    if (curval==1 && callstatus==0) {
      $('#callertype').html(callby);
      $('#myModal').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: true});
    }
  }, 3000);

  // The myModal div is not always there. We only need 1 subscription
  // for this to work.
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // if the modal box is shown, subscribe to the shown event
    // and automatically close in 60 seconds.
    var $modal = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("timeout");
      $modal.modal('hide');
    }, 60000);
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title modal-title-100">New call by  <small id="callertype"></small></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="acceptcall" onclick="acceptcall()" data-dismiss="modal"> Accept</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-sm-3 mdlbtn" id="declinecall" onclick="declinecall()" data-dismiss="modal">Decline</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```